# What uniquely defines the RequestContinuation token in CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am going through paging the results returning from CosmosDb and for that I need to understand what uniquely defines the `FeedOptions.RequestContinuation` string.
I can make the paging work, so that is not the issue, but its uniqueness is needed for our purposes. What astonished me, for instance, is that the RequestContinuation token is not the same if I perform the following:

-Create data in the emulator for two pocos

-Query items with MaxItemCount

-Get the first RequestContinuation token and store it

-Delete all data (manually in the emulator explorer) and recreating them. The data are exactly the same except for the auto-generated values such as the Id

-Same query with the same MaxItemCount

-Get the token again and store it

The result is that the token last retrieved is not the same as the one in the first method.

Is it possible to have a detailed breakdown on what uniquely defines a RequestContinuation token?
Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on "uniqueness is needed for our purposes" for context? You mention that described scenario already DOES provide you unique tokens, so  is this uniqueness theme related to your last question at all?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear: I have only one question: What uniquely defines a RequestContinuation token? This means which parameters define it? I am implementing a scenario that will only work if I know under which conditions I have one and only one requestcontinuation token. Said differently, a requestcontinuation token is a mathematical function of parameters and I assume it is one to one, i.e. for one set of parameter values, I get exactly one token: What are these parameters? Example, it depends on the query and maxitemcount, but what else, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuation token should be treated as an opaque string. The actual value depends on the query execution plan, system generated IDs, configurations like page size, degree of parallelism, API version, and more factors. You won't get the same continuation token twice for the same query however.

Comment: If I don't get the same token twice for the same query, then I do not see how I can rely on it for going through paging. I am bit confused, hence a refinement of my original question would be: in which scenario(s) I can rely on the token?

Comment: For the same collection, against the same data, you can rely on the continuation token. Makes sense?