# Meaning of MaxItemCount = null vs MaxItemCount= -1 in CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Setting `MaxItemCount = null` in Documentdb returns 100 items in my case but what is the exact mechanism or logic behind this? A further comment on how it compares to `MaxItemCount = -1` for a large number of documents would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you set `MaxItemCount` to null, it falls back to the service (REST API) default, which is 100. When you set to -1, the service determines the optimal page count for you dynamically based on the query (which usually sends as many results as possible, up to 1000s).

If your question is why the default is not -1, this is for backwards compatibility. Future versions of the Cosmos DB REST API may use -1, as this is what we recommend for most new applications.

Comment: Understood, I may point to another unrelated question but still theoretical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545528/what-uniquely-defines-the-requestcontinuation-token-in-cosmosdb

Comment: I just figured out that this property seems to override any `OFFSET n LIMIT 10` values in the query... did not expect that. The query in the Emulator/data explorer returns 2 (due to where-clause and the offset). The GetItemQueryStreamIterator returns 10.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add, if you set MaxItemCount to -1, the response will be limited to 4MB. This is documented in [Request limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits)